# 500 Internal Server Error?

Tags: php, mysql, smarty, apache

Recently, I put my project which is php+smarty+mysql in my httpd server. But I encountered an error that says:

```
500 Internal Server Error
```

My OS is archlinux, and the httpd server and php were installed like this:

```
sudo pacman -S apache php
```

If I use a test native php file which contains the following:

```
  <html>
    <head>
    <title>PHP Test Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    This is Arch Linux, running PHP.
    <?php
      phpinfo();
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

it runs correctly. It tells me that the php can work well. But why is my project with smarty not working? Is there any one who has encountered this problem?

Comment: Did you create a directory structure?

Comment: If this were a multiple choice physics problem, I'd pick "Insufficient details."

Comment: what do you mean about "create a directory structure"

Comment: Can your locate your apache error_log (try in /var/log/httpd)? If so there may be some clues in there, if you're still at a loss try posting the last few lines of the log in the question.

Answer (score 7):

With the info you provided it's difficult to say.

Error 500 happens because you did some error in the code that is supposed to produce the page, or the code generates some unhandled exception.
My suggestion is to visit the page that gives you the 500 error, and then try to comment out all your code. See if the issue is still present. If not, uncomment the code until you find the critical part that originates the error. Could be anything, a typo, a file not found, a logical error, anything.

Also, check in the webserver logs, if you can read them.

Comment: The page is smarty's tpl file, and it display nothing. The error message "500 Internal Server Error" is catched by firebug tool.

Comment: firebug catches whatever your server generates. That 500 is returned by your server. Check if you have errors in your template file, or the php/smarty substitution process.

Answer (score 3):

Look in your Apache error log (often found at `/var/log/httpd/error_log`, though this varies greatly).  It will have more information about the server error.

Comment: ther error_log file doesn't conaint any error message about the error.

Comment: That's very unusual.  I'd recommend making sure you're looking at the right file; virtual hosts can have their own error logs and such.

Answer (score 2):

Check to make sure that any .htaccess files are correct (syntax wise).

Answer (score 2):

just happened to me and wanted to write down the solution.

The configured Smarty cache directory (/var/cache/Smarty) was configured with incorrect permissions, the apache process needs to create files in that directory.

This is the directory you set with the compile_dir directive.

BTW, the error_log file doesn't show anything with this error, Firebug shows a 500 Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the error details by checking error.log file inside

> /var/log/apache2

in ubuntu 16.04