# mysqli update query using ajax in wordpress theme

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am working on a wordpress based application where I need to change the status of listed orders using ajax.
The below code gives me the following error:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

I can not figure out why this is not working. Please help me out.

HTML:

```
<select id="status-<?php echo $order_id[$xx]; ?>" name="status-<?php echo $order_id[$xx]; ?>" onChange="return statuschange(this, '<?php echo $order_id[$xx]; ?>');">
    <option value="0"<?php if ($status_code[$xx] == 0){ echo' selected="selected"'; }; ?>>incoming</option>
    <option value="1"<?php if ($status_code[$xx] == 1){ echo' selected="selected"'; }; ?>>processing</option>
    <option value="2"<?php if ($status_code[$xx] == 2){ echo' selected="selected"'; }; ?>>processed</option>
    <option value="3"<?php if ($status_code[$xx] == 3){ echo' selected="selected"'; }; ?>>packing</option>
    <option value="4"<?php if ($status_code[$xx] == 4){ echo' selected="selected"'; }; ?>>ready</option>
    <option value="5"<?php if ($status_code[$xx] == 5){ echo' selected="selected"'; }; ?>>posted</option>
    <option value="6"<?php if ($status_code[$xx] == 6){ echo' selected="selected"'; }; ?>>received</option>
    <option value="7"<?php if ($status_code[$xx] == 7){ echo' selected="selected"'; }; ?>>returned</option>
    <option value="8"<?php if ($status_code[$xx] == 8){ echo' selected="selected"'; }; ?>>deleted</option>
</select>
```

JS (at the end of the file where the above HTML code is):

```
function statuschange(element, orderid){
    var oldValue = element.defaultValue;
    var newValue = element.value;
    var admincomment = prompt("Change order status?\n\nAdd comment:", "");
    if (admincomment != null) {
        var newValueecn = encodeURI(newValue);
        var admincommentenc = encodeURI(admincomment);
        var orderidenc = encodeURI(orderid);
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () { if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) { element.defaultValue = newValue; location.reload(true); console.log(xmlhttp.responseText); } }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://www.mydomain.tld/wp-content/themes/mycustomtheme/changestatus.php?newstatusz=" + newValueecn + "&comment=" + admincommentenc + "&orderid=" + orderidenc, true);
            xmlhttp.send(); }
        } else {
        element.value = element.defaultValue; } };
```

PHP (changestatus.php):

```
function cleaninput($input){
    $input = trim($input);
    $input = stripslashes($input);
    $input = htmlspecialchars($input);
    return $input;
}
if(isset($_GET['newstatusz'])){
    $newstatusz = cleaninput($_GET['newstatusz']);
} else { exit; }
if(isset($_GET['comment'])){
    $comment = cleaninput($_GET['comment']);
} else { exit; }
if(isset($_GET['orderid'])){
    $orderid = cleaninput($_GET['orderid']);
} else { exit; }
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$userloggedin = $current_user->user_login;
$mysqli1 = new mysqli("localhost", "myuser", "mypass", "mydatabase");
if ($mysqli1->connect_error){ die("DB connect error: " . $mysqli1->connect_error); };
$mysqli1->set_charset("utf8");
$newstatusz = $mysqli1->real_escape_string($newstatusz);
$userloggedin = $mysqli1->real_escape_string($userloggedin);
$comment = $mysqli1->real_escape_string($comment);
$mysqli1->query("UPDATE poszter_admin SET statusz_kod = '$newstatusz', user = '$userloggedin', comment = '$comment' WHERE order_id = '$orderid'");
$mysqli1->close();
exit;
```

Comment: Search your server's error log and post the detailed error

Comment: Did you go through: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210380/500-internal-server-error ?

Comment: @dimlucas checking the error log helped me out:
`PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function wp_get_current_user()`
I changed my code so the user login is passed from the wp page to the handler script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved thanks to the comment of @dimlucas

The wp_get_current_user() function was not defined in my PHP code.
I have made a workaround to avoid using this function there.

The working code is below.

JS:

```
function statuschange(element, orderid){
    var oldValue = element.defaultValue;
    var newValue = element.value;
    var userlogin = document.getElementById('userloggedin').innerHTML;
    var admincomment = prompt("Change order status?\n\nAdd comment:", "");
    if (admincomment != null) {
        var newValueecn = encodeURI(newValue);
        var admincommentenc = encodeURI(admincomment);
        var orderidenc = encodeURI(orderid);
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () { if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) { element.defaultValue = newValue; location.reload(true); console.log(xmlhttp.responseText); } }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://www.mydomain.tld/wp-content/themes/mycustomtheme/changestatus.php?newstatusz=" + newValueecn + "&comment=" + admincommentenc + "&orderid=" + orderidenc + "&userloggedin=" + userlogin, true);
            xmlhttp.send(); }
        } else {
        element.value = element.defaultValue; } };
```

PHP (changestatus.php):

```
function cleaninput($input){
    $input = trim($input);
    $input = stripslashes($input);
    $input = htmlspecialchars($input);
    return $input;
}
if(isset($_GET['newstatusz'])){
    $newstatusz = cleaninput($_GET['newstatusz']);
} else { exit; }
if(isset($_GET['comment'])){
    $comment = cleaninput($_GET['comment']);
} else { exit; }
if(isset($_GET['orderid'])){
    $orderid = cleaninput($_GET['orderid']);
} else { exit; }
if(isset($_GET['userloggedin'])){
$userloggedin = cleaninput($_GET['userloggedin']);
} else { exit; }
$mysqli1 = new mysqli("localhost", "myuser", "mypass", "mydatabase");
if ($mysqli1->connect_error){ die("DB connect error: " . $mysqli1->connect_error); };
$mysqli1->set_charset("utf8");
$newstatusz = $mysqli1->real_escape_string($newstatusz);
$userloggedin = $mysqli1->real_escape_string($userloggedin);
$comment = $mysqli1->real_escape_string($comment);
$orderid = $mysqli1->real_escape_string($orderid);
$mysqli1->query("UPDATE poszter_admin SET statusz_kod = '$newstatusz', user = '$userloggedin', comment = '$comment' WHERE order_id = '$orderid'");
$mysqli1->close();
exit;
```

Thank you!